# Azure Cognitive Search: Facet "values" for DateTime field

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I think I'm not understanding to do what I want. I want to offer a list of facets that look like this:

- Created Today (123)
- Created in the last week (3,455)
- Created in the last month (12,234)
- Created in the last year (112,234)

The [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents) say ""facet=lastRenovationDate,values:2010-02-01T00:00:00Z" produces two buckets: one for hotels renovated before February 2010, and one for hotels renovated February 1, 2010 or later.

Logically, I'm not understanding how to create these buckets. There's no documentation explaining how to offer ranges of dates, and I can't figure out the right combo.

I can figure out the code, but logically how would I accomplish the above? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Assumptions

Assuming your field that you want to facet on is `createdDate` and is of type `Edm.DateTimeOffset`. For your requirement, I think there will be some calculations that you'd have to do after you get the facet data back.

These are the dates you are interested in

**(today)** - 2021-08-12T00:00:00Z

**yesterday** - (today - 1 day) 2021-08-11T00:00:00Z

**last week** - (yesterday - 1 week) 2021-08-04T00:00:00Z

**last month** - (4 weeks back to 1 weeks back) 2021-07-12T00:00:00Z

**last year** - (1 year ago to last month) 2020-08-12T00:00:00Z

#### Query and Response

so you will specify 4 values in your facet - yesterday, last week, last month, last year. I will first use these names in the actual query to make it more readable. The second is the actual query you will make

1. human readable query - `facet=createdDate,values:last year | last month | last week | yesterday`
2. actual search query - `facet=createdDate,values:2020-08-12T00:00:00Z| 2021-07-12T00:00:00Z | 2021-08-04T00:00:00Z | 2021-08-11T00:00:00Z`

This will result in 5 buckets of data as follows.

**a** - everything older than last year (you don't need this, you can throw it away)

**b** - everything from last year to last month

**c** - everything from last month to last week

**d** - everythng from last week to yesterday

**e** - everything from yesterday to today

#### Solution

Now the following will be the calculations in order to get the ranges you need.

- Created Today (123) - `e`
- Created in the last week (3,455) - `d + e`
- Created in the last month (12,234) - `c + d + e`
- Created in the last year (112,234) - `b + c + d + e`
- Created prior to last year (547,838) - `a`

Comment: Hey, wow! This is amazingly helpful! Thank you so much, Michael!
I"ve gotten this all to the point of passing in the proper values, in the order you mentioned:
createdate,values:2020-08-12T23:17:46.1594778Z|2021-07-12T23:17:46.1595629Z|2021-08-05T23:17:46.1595642Z|2021-08-11T23:17:46.1595806Z

Now I'm just working with the Response.Facets, to do some data manipulation as you've described. You definitely deserve some of my "reputation" haha, it won't let me award it yet but it's coming your way.

I'll let you know once it's completely working, thanks again!